# sed command not working on Centos in java code

Tags: centos, sed, java

I am running a java code which runs an `sed` command on a `.txt` file to remove BOM on Centos. I get the following Error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
```

Java Code:

```
        String[] args = {"sed","-i","'1s/^\\xEF\\xBB\\xBF//'","/tmp/output.txt"};
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(args);
        Process p = processBuilder.start();
        int exitVal = p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));


        String line = null;
        // read the output from the command
        while ((line = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }
        // read any errors from the attempted command
        logger.info("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
        while ((line = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            logger.info("Error: " + line);
        }
```

Comment: Apache's [Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) library has a utility class [BOMInputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/input/BOMInputStream.html) to read streams with BOMs and the default constructor skips the BOM (see Example 1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message indicates that `sed` does not know what command `'` (single quote, the first character in the expression) is.

Remove the single quotes around the `sed` expression. You may need it in the shell to protect the string from being interpreted by the shell, but when calling `sed` from another language, you won't need them.

Also, calling external tools from Java or any other language seems a bit clumsy. I would suppose you'd be able to do these sorts of modifications from within the language directly, possibly by using some library.

Comment: thanks it worked